The final step of proving Seesaw Theorem
My question is about the final step of seesaw theorem, which was already stated in this old post.
First, I think a fibre for a sheaf of $\mathcal O_{X\times Y}$-module( in the post mentioned above, this is denoted by $F$, meaning a cokernel) should be over a point of $X\times Y$, say $(x,y)$, in order to apply Nakayama's lemma.
Second, I doubt whether op's understanding of the application of Nakayama's lemma is right. Since if we replace $\pi^*\pi_* L$ by the trivial line bundle
$\mathcal O_{X\times Y}$, everything seems to go smoothly, which shows if a line bundle on $X\times Y$ is trivial when restricted to all fibers over $y\in Y$, then it is trivial. This sounds wrong.
When I was writing this post, it suddenly occurs to me that the point may be the existence of some homomorphsim from a possible candidate for the expression of such line bundles. We certainly have a homomorphism $\alpha: \pi^*\pi_* L\to L$, and if we show that this is an isomorphism, then we are done.
If my understanding is right, then second confusion is gone. So is this understanding right?
For the first confusion, I come up with an argument. If this natural homomorphism is not an isomorphism, then for at least one stalk, say over $p=(x,y)$, the localized homomorphism $\alpha_p$ is zero. So $\alpha$ is zero on some neighborhood $U\times V$ of $p$. So at least on $U\times \{y\}$, $\alpha$ cannot be an isomorphism(since restriction(pull-back) preserves cokernels). At first I thought restriction to the point $(x,y)$ may work, but restriction to one point and the stalk over a point may be different things. Is this argument right?

By the suggestion of my seminar supervisor, I finally get it. On affine opens, if the cokernel of the natural morphism is $N^\sim$ for some $A\otimes_k B$-module $N$, then the condition that fibers over all $y\in Y$ are $0$ means by Nakayama that the restriction of scalars $N_B=0$, and thus $N=0$, so we get the subjectivity.
